# Entity Framework better table/column count

Tags: entity-framework

I was wondering on how to do the following:
I have a base class like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have 2 classes that inherit from the base:

```
public class ClassA : BaseClass 
{
     // some properties
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass 
{
     // some properties
}
```

Now this generates the Articles database with columns for each class: `ClassA_Id`, `ClassB_Id`, ...

Isn't there an way to have it generate less columns/tables? because when the application grows it will have more and more of those columns, which will be Null most of the time.

I tried some mapping, but it creates a seperate table for each class (like: ClassAArticles, ClassBArticles, ...)
Or complains that it can't have the same column mapped for 2 entities.

Comment: What are the types/numbers of the additional properties; will they be common across the derived classes?

Answer (score 0):

On your Context, you can add on OnModelCreating a Map, defining that you classes generates from the Base.

Will be somethine like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>()
        .Map(m => m.ToTable("BaseClass"))
        .Map<ClassA>(m => m.ToTable("ClassA"))
        .Map<ClassB>(m => m.ToTable("ClassB"));
}
```

This will generate 3 tables, where ClassA and ClassB will have only Id field that references the Id field of the Base table.